# What to do if people discuss a problem outside of Stack Exchange by private communication?

Tags: discussion, communication

I was looking for some explanation in the FAQs about this problem but I could not find anything.

I will explain:

1. User A asks a question about X
2. User B starts helping him in the comments.
3. After a few comments, User A asks User B to talk with him by email (giving his email in a comment)
4. User B answers yes and posts his email too.

I want to discuss two things:

- First, is it legal to try to solve questions where at first you use Stack Overflow as platform to get solved and then you solve with another Stack Overflow user by themselves without letting us know what happens?
- Second, why would these people resort to this method instead of using Stack Overflow like all of us?

Answer (score 2):

> First, is it legal to try to solve questions where at first you use Stack Overflow as platform to get solved and then you solve with another Stack Overflow user by themselves without letting us know what happens?

Yes, it's legal, just like it's legal to post the same question on a site which is a competitor of Stack Overflow, hoping to get a faster/better answer there. Of course, it would be nice if they post the resolution of the problem here as well, but they are by no means required to do so.

It's *also* legal for the Stack Overflow community to edit out e-mail addresses or flag/remove comments which contain them.

> Second, why would these people resort to this method instead of using SO like all of us?

Well, sometimes e-mail simply works better than a Q&A site, e.g. to send a large test project, or to arrange a phone or video call.